# Perl Core function like File::Which

Tags: perl

I am wondering if there are a perl core function/module which implements something like what File::Which (https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Which) on by using core Perl without installing any external library .

for example if i want to check an executable on Perl

my @paths = where 'perl' ->  will return all the exectuables of perl

which could be good to check if library is installed on the system with Perl ?

for example python3 offer such function on the core : https://docs.python.org/dev/library/shutil.html#shutil.which

do Perl have such function on core and didn't need to install any library or i am missing something?

Comment: What's wrong with installing modules?

Comment: nothing wrong , i just expect this basic functionality to be on the core exactly like Text::CSV which considered basic functionality today which also not on the core

Comment: The module is 175 lines of code with no external (non-core) dependencies. You could model a quick solution off of the source code. As for why it isn't in core, let's not be too hard on Perl. The only benefit the module provides above and beyond /usr/bin/which is portability for entire operating systems that lack the which utility (Windows for instance).

Comment: For what it's worth, the Perl community has developed many solutions to make non-core modules work for more use cases. For example, [fatpack](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::FatPacker), [Carton](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carton), and [PAR](https://metacpan.org/pod/pp).

Comment: i agree with you ,those tools are awesome if you want to bundle external library like plotting charts ,or some rest api ,but there are some specific use cases it will be more convienent if theya re on the core,like reading password from STDIN without echoing  and not depending on external module , if you compare Perl to Python or even Go the Perl core missing many daily tasks functionailtiy where you need all the time to install external libraries ,i am not against external modules ,there are many modules on cpan have high quality and better any other equivlant libraries from other languages .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer is can_run from this core module IPC::CMD which can do the above job

https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Cmd#$path-=-can_run(-PROGRAM-)

```
use IPC::Cmd qw(can_run);

my $full_path = can_run('perl') or warn 'perl is not installed!';
```